# Excel function - if no results then make the cell '0'

Tags: excel, excel-2007

How can I edit this array function to make the result display 0 instead of #N/A if there are no results? I've tried using IF statements with it but can't get it it work...

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&I18&"'!$h$1:$h$999"),MATCH(1,(INDIRECT("'"&I18&"'!$a$1:$a$999")="Last 20 Games by Venue")*(INDIRECT("'"&I18&"'!$b$1:$b$999")=O18),0))
```

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2007 you can just wrap an IFERROR function around your formula - the syntax is

`=IFERROR(original_formula,default_result)`

so to get zero instead of #N/A use this version

`=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&I18&"'!$h$1:$h$999"),MATCH(1,(INDIRECT("'"&I18&"'!$a$1:$a$999")="Last 20 Games by Venue")*(INDIRECT("'"&I18&"'!$b$1:$b$999")=O18),0)),0)`